# How to Integrate SVN in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2017

I want to integrate `SVN` in `Visual Studio 2017`. But cannot find the option from where `SVN` could be connected.

SVN version : TortoiseSVN 1.9.5, Build 27581 - 64 Bit

Comment: Go through https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html

Comment: You should try VisualSVN https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-Subversionintegration

Comment: For simple commands, e.g. log+diff, you can setup external tools as detailed here: https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-Subversionintegration). VisualSVN 6.0 nicely integrates with VS2017 and is free under Community License (on non-domain computers).

[image]

I guess that another option would be to try [AnkhSVN 2.7](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio).

BTW, what @rajusharma mentioned is not really an 'integration'. That instruction just adds TortoiseSVN's commands to Visual Studio and it quite outdated. It was written at the times when there the only free edition of Visual Studio was Express that did not support third party extensions. There is Visual Studio Community Edition nowadays and you can freely install VisualSVN or AnkhSVN to integrate SVN with your IDE.

PS I'm with VisualSVN Team, so consider me biased. :)

Comment: Thanks alot @bahrep

Comment: @wha7ever VisualSVN does not use a “weird” license and is trusted by thousands of developers.

Comment: @wha7ever What’s your question? You can use the plugin for free on machines that are not in Active Directory and there are also other free options. Please note that you can read a brief summary of licensing options at https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/.

Comment: @bahrep I see you pointed license stuff out in the second sentence. I did not pay attention and just followed link. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

TSVN is also a good choice.

I once used VisualSVN extension. However, I find VisualSVN has an issue when upgrading Nuget packages containing resource files, it always mark the resource files deleted and added, that's odd. Now I switch to TSVN, it seems very light-weight and convenient.

[image]

Comment: Current TSVN version can be found under https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.TSVN

Comment: FYI: this one is MIT licensed.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

[AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

With this tool you can:

- Add code to source version

[image]

- See the changes on the Solution Explorer

[image]

- And all the stuff that you cand do with Tortoise SVN on Windows Explorer